# Run "mvn package" on "Build project" in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-3

I have maven java project in eclipse. I right click project, choose "Build project" and I want "mvn package" get invoked automatically. Is it possible?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Rightclick on your pom.xml and choose `"Run as" -> "Maven build.."` and put in Goals:`package`.
If you now select "run" (CTRL + F11) it will run automatically if you select these run configuration.

And as Chris said, [m2e](http://eclipse.org/m2e/) is required.

Comment: This answers the question "how do I package with a keyboard shortcut," but it doesn't answer the question of how to leverage "build project" to package, which is what was asked.

Answer (score 2):

You should install the m2eclipse eclipse plugin.  This will take care of properly building maven projects in eclipse.  The link for m2eclipse is [here](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/)