# 403 Forbidden - Deploying Spring Boot application in Weblogic

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, weblogic, weblogic12c

I have an application that I'm currently trying to convert to Spring Boot but I'm having issues getting Weblogic configured to run the application. I get 403 Forbidden response on HTTP request.

---

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

**This is my `@SpringBootApplication` class.**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AgisSpringApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AgisSpringApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext context) throws ServletException {

    }
}
```

---

**This is my `weblogic.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <wls:weblogic-web-app
        xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd
        http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app
        http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.7/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <wls:weblogic-version>12.1.3</wls:weblogic-version>
    <wls:context-root>agis-spring</wls:context-root>
    <wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-application-packages>
            <wls:package-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:package-name>
        </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    </wls:container-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

---

**And this is my only controller at the moment**

```
@RestController
public class MapController {

    private TemplateService templateService;

    public MapController(TemplateService templateService) {
        this.templateService = templateService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String getName() throws Exception {
        return templateService.getTemplate("map.vm");
    }
}
```

---

`pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>agis-spring</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>agis-spring</name>
    <description></description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: did your pack your artifact as `war`? did you exclude embedded tomcat from it?

Answer (score 4):

1) your `Application.java` doesn't look correct.
Try this one:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application 
        extends SpringBootServletInitializer 
        implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

2) Make sure your `weblogic.xml` is placed under `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/`.

3) Make sure you package the app into `war`.

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

4) Make sure embedded tomcat is disabled.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

5) I'm not sure if `wls:package-name` can be specified as wildcart. According to [spring-boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-weblogic) it should be like this:

```
<wls:package-name>org.slf4j</wls:package-name>
```

6) Build the `war` artifact by performing `mvn clean package`.

The `.war` artifact will be placed to `your-app/build/lib`. Use this file for deploying into the server.

Hope that some of this hints will solve the problem.

Comment: Going to try all of these things now. Thankyou! I'll respond momentarily.

Comment: When we were using a previous version of spring, the `weblogic.xml` was located in a different directory outside of `src/main`. Does this really matter?

Comment: Not exactly, It depends on how you build the app. The main idea is that after packaging it should be located like this `your-app.war/WEB-INF/weblogic.xml`. Try to open your `war` file using any archive manager and make sure the folder structure is ok.

Comment: I think I may be misunderstanding the process... I can't actually find the war file. It isn't in the root directory of the project.

Comment: I have added my `pom.xml`

Comment: I've added option 6 to clarify how to build the war. However I see that you haven't turned off embedded tomcat in your pom.xml

Comment: I'm using eclipse, and I assumed eclipse was doing this for me?

Comment: To build it with eclipse you have to do something [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14026449/2065796). 

But how do you deploy it into the server? Using eclipse as well?

Comment: I run `startWebLogic` from the command-line, added the project via the web console, and it just worked. It was all set up for me when I got here. And it would automatically refresh with any changes to the source.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139620/discussion-between-qbolt-and-oleksandr-shpota).